# Google Hangouts Screen Share Black Screen Error

Tags: linux, google-chrome, arch-linux

I've been facing an issue with Google Hangouts full-screen sharing.
While doing a full-screen share on Google Hangouts, all I see is a black screen and nothing else:

[image: This]

But it is possible to share individual screens separately:

[image: This]

I have had this problem for the past two weeks, but before that it wasn't an issue. In order to see what's causing this, I ran Chrome from terminal and got the following error when I started full-screen sharing:

> [7869:7875:0113/150458:ERROR:interface_registry.cc(99)] Capability spec prevented service service:content_browser from binding interface: mojom::ResourceUsageReporter

- Chrome-Version: 55.0.2883.87
- OS: Arch-Linux
- GPU: AMD Radeon HD

I've also tried other methods like clearing cookies and cache of Chrome, clear all Google accounts and restart, but nothing seems to work. 
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm using gnome on Manjaro and I have the same issue. It seems to be a Wayland problem. I logout from wayland session and start a Xorg session and the hangout works.

[image]

Comment: Yes, It is a problem with Wayland. I tried it on **Gnome on Xorg** and other **Desktop Enviroments** and it works perfectly.

Comment: same, 4 years later

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04, I've the window & ubuntu , in ubutu I've two users, but i didn't see any setting icon when i logged in

Answer (score 0):

This is for the **KDE Plasma Wayland** guys, as I was suffering from the same problem.

Just while **signing in**, for Arch Linux guys on **KDE plasma** switch to **Plasma X11** instead of **Plasma Wayland**.

If there then also this doesn't happen install these:

- pipewire
- xorg-destop-kde
- Kwin

**Reboot**

And while **signing in** again with **KDE X11** this problem might get away.